Unity iOS XCode project does not find libc++ headers
after upgrading from Unity 2020.3.48f1 to 2022.3.28f1 and exporting the project as xcode project to build it for iOS on a Mac it does not compile anymore with the following error:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS17.5.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/clocale:43:5 <clocale> tried including <locale.h> but didn't find libc++'s <locale.h> header. This usually means that your header search paths are not configured properly. The header search paths should contain the C++ Standard Library headers before any C Standard Library, and you are probably using compiler flags that make that not be the case. 

The project uses FireBase push notifications, therefore I use pod install and open the newly created Unity-iPhone.xcworkspace
I use
Xcode 15.4 (15F31d) (latest Version)
CocoaPods 1.15.2 (latest Version)
MacOS 14.5 (23F79)
The header search path currently look like this:
Header Search Paths
Do you have an idea what could be the problem here?
I already tried to add /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include to the header search paths but this led to a lot of other errors and seems not to be the solution (see screenshot).
New Errors

You definitely shouldn't be adding desktop sdk paths to an ios project
